# Finding Nearest Line Segments to Point in all direction?

Tags: routes, geometry, gis, shapely

**Background**

There are several lines(segments) and a point. I need to find the nearest line in all direction which means in 360 degree. The question is related to a route algorithm. For example, a start point is not on the road, so it needs to find a road and execute Dijkstra or A* algorithm.

One answer is that a radial sweep by constructing a series of lines from the known Point and intersections are created between lines the radial line. Then compared with the distance, the nearest line in all direction are found. The link is : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81613/finding-nearest-line-segments-to-point-using-shapely

However, when the step of angle is big, it may miss some lines. So I ask above question.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63LI9.png)

In the above image, the angle between neighboring radial lines is 30 degree. In fact, the known point can arrive the line in the blue circle by a radial line but the radial line cannot be created because the step of angle is 30 degree. When the angle is very small, for example, 10 degree, a radial line may be created and intersects the line in the blue circle.

However, it spend a lot of time when the angle is small, I want to find an efficient method.

The question is related the follow issue. There is a start point, an end point and road graph. However, the start point is not on a line(road), I need to make a road between the point and graph,   so the question is proposed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxmd6.png)
[image]

I need to find the shortest distance from the start point and end point. How to find the green line
in the following image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gbbV.png)

[image]

**Summary**

Can anyone recommend an alternative method to find the nearest line to a point in all direction(360 degree). In the above route issue, Can anyone provide a solution?

at Present, a radial sweep is used and the angle step is 30. However ,the angle is not so small so it may missing some lines(road). Could someone provide a better solution or any ideas?

**the key of the question**
The key of the question is that when angle step is big, for example, 30 degree, the radial line can't intersect some short lines. However, if the angle step is set as 1 degree, the computing time may not be accepted.

look the following image:
[image]

Comment: The key of the question is that when angle step is big, for example, 30 degree, the radial line can't intersect some short lines. However, if the angle step is set as 1 degree, the computing time may not be accepted.

Comment: Please tell me what is the reason to employ the said method.
If simply calculate distance between the point and each line segments, what is not good?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you can put all segment ends (and perhaps intersections of segments) into a list/array

Sort list by angle

Walk through sorted list, keeping additional list of active segments

When you meet the first point of segment, check if it is closer than current closest segment. Add segment to active list.

When you meet the last point of segment, remove it from active list and check what segment from active list is the closest one.

Example:

[image]

After sorting by angle we have point sequence `[A,L,C,M,B,E,D,G,F,I,H,K,J,A_again]`

We need to determine the closest segment for intervals:

```
angle interval      active segments   closest segment
start
-------------------------------------------------------
A                   KL, AB               KL
L                   AB                   AB  
C                   AB, CD               AB 
M                   AB, CD               CD
B                   CD                   CD
E                   CD, EF               EF
D                   EF                   EF
.....
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually I used the method you mentioned to find the nearest line by comparing distance in every angle( 0 degree, 30 degree, 60 degree,... 330 degree). However, the key question is that when degree step is not so small, the radial lines can't intersect some short lines.

Comment: No, this is fully different method. You don't need to check every angle, just key points (ends, intersections if exist)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. What is the method of comparing a segment is closer to another segment?

Comment: Just calculate distance form O to point at the first segment and to the second segment at given angle. If segments intersects here, look at cross product sign (when segment directions have similar - say CCW orientation)

Comment: In my project, the number of segments have more than 10,000，so the number of endpoints may 20,000, I am concerned that the computing time may much.

Comment: If you need to treat segment set onece, then I proposed the best approach (I hope). But if the segments instantly change  - perhaps there exists some data structure to omit treatment of "shadow" segments (fully behind others), but to build it you must walk through all segments. Also keeping it in persistent state should require some efforts. Look at `visibility graph`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand what you are looking for, but at first sight I think you could use [geopandas.sjoin_nearest](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.sjoin_nearest.html#geopandas.GeoDataFrame.sjoin_nearest) to find the nearest line for a point?